# Java Selenium - Select a WebElement based on value attribute

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was wondering if there was a way to find an element on a webpage based on the value attribute.

```
<option value="abc">Some text here</option>
<option value="bcd">Some text here</option>
```

I figured I could just create a list of WebElements based on the tag name and traverse each one using .getAttribute("value"), but I was wondering if there was a more effective way of doing this similar to the way you can find an element based on its text using:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), '" + term + "')]"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[value=\"abc\"]"))
```

and you would change the value of value depending on what you were trying to find.

Answer (score 0):

To locate the element with `value="abc"` on a webpage `based on the *value* attribute of **abc** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors):

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("option[value='abc']"))
  ```
- [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath):

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//option[@value='abc']"))
  ```